# Roasted duck carcass - what is this dish called?

Tags: duck

I've never broken down a duck before, so I found myself briefly watching this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTJR6-HU6OY

At the end, the chef mentions that in southern France, the carcass is sometimes sprinkled with coarse salt, roasted in a fast oven for some amount of time until it is GBD, and then picked apart by hand as a finger food. For the life of me though, I can't seem to find any references to this at all. Is anyone familiar with this dish? What is it called??

I've got fleur de sel on hand, and I think it would work great!

Comment: GBD = Golden, Brown and Delicious (Just for those who might not immediately get the acronym)

Comment: OP Looking for an answer, I found a similar thing in China. Frying the carcass after the Peking Duck! [Simply Gluttonous](http://www.simplygluttonous.com/2014/06/kunshan-china-beijing-roast-duck.html)  YUM!

Comment: I have found a reference to it. There is a recipe called Roasted duck carcass in [Cooking and Travelling In South-West France](http://www.amazon.com/Cooking-Travelling-South-West-Stephanie-Alexander/dp/1920989242) by Stephanie Alexander and Simon Griffiths.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Does the book mention the French name for the dish?

Comment: Maybe, but I can't see it. I *have* asked the only owner of the book on Amazon that has reviewed it. <shrug> We'll see!

Comment: This sounds like a cooks dish. Probably it's called leftovers for the kitchen staff and has no official name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this recipe on 
[supertoinette](http://www.supertoinette.com/recette/571/carcasses_grillees_de_to.html) .

The name of the dish is "Carcasses de canards grillées" which translates to roasted duck carcasses. It states below the name that "These carcasses of roasted ducks are a specialty of the Southwest!"

If you use Google, you can translate the page and get the recipe and instructions. This particular recipe uses ingredients in addition to the salt but, as with most recipes, I would expect that there are many variations.

Comment: Nice!!! now, I just have to convince "the powers that be" to let me cook some duck at home.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I was looking for!! Now I need to get a few more ducks! :)

Comment: you could probably do the same thing with chicken carcasses